# How to fix 'Typerror is undefined' message for a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, background-image, onmouseover

I am trying to manipulate the background image as soon as the user hovers over a selected option. I tested my code in firebug and loaded up the page. Instantly I get:

> TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName(...).style is undefined

```
var bg = document.getElementsByTagName("html").style.backgroundColor = "white";
```

and for the hover I get:

> TypeError: bg.document is undefined

```
bg.document.getElementsByTagName("html").style.backgroundImage = "url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/500_USD_note%3B_series_of_1934%3B_obverse.jpg')";
```

How do I fix this error?

**HTML CODE:**

```
<form>
    <!--show a large print of green font color and size money-->
    Select your DSLR budget range:
    <select id="budgetSel" onChange="onChange();">
        <option value="selectOneBudget" selected="selected">Select one</option>
        <option value="fiveHundredDollars" onMouseOver="changeBackgroundImage(this);">&lt; $500</option>
        <option value="thousandDollars" onMouseOver="changeBackgroundImage(this);">&lt; $1000</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
html{
background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8a/1000_USD_note%3B_series_of_1934%3B_obverse.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
/*-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;*/
background-size: cover;
min-width:1300px; /*keep the same width when resizing*/
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var bg = document.getElementsByTagName("html").style.backgroundColor = "white";
// function to dynamically change the background image when user hovers over an option in select menu
function changeBackgroundImage(bg)
{
   bg.document.getElementsByTagName("html").style.backgroundImage = "url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/500_USD_note%3B_series_of_1934%3B_obverse.jpg')";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as its name implies:

```
document.getElementsByTagName
```

returns a collection of tags not a single node, I said a collection because it doesn't actually return an array but it returns an array-like object.

If you only need to get the html node, you can simply do:

```
document.lastChild.style.backgroundColor = "white";
```

and also

```
document.documentElement.style.backgroundColor = "white";
```

but if you need to find it using a finder function like that, you should do this instead:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.backgroundColor = "white";
```

and also this one:

```
document.querySelector("html").style.backgroundColor = "white";
```

Comment: I'm getting one error `TypeError: bg.document is undefined` on     `bg.document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/500_USD_note%3B_series_of_1934%3B_obverse.jpg')";`

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns array of match elements, 
so you should use index `0` in your case.

Should be

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style
```

instead of

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html").style
```

Comment: I'm getting one error `TypeError: bg.document is undefined` on     `bg.document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/500_USD_note%3B_series_of_1934%3B_obverse.jpg')";`