# TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName(...).className is undefined

Tags: javascript

I keep getting

> TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName(...).className is undefined

What's up with that, I don't really get it.

```
function test(){
    if ( document.getElementsByTagName("body").className.match(/(?:^|\s)test(?!\S)/) ){
        document.getElementsByTagName("body").className += " test";
        alert("test");
    }
}

document.onload = test();
```

Comment: It's in the name: getElementsByTagName - elements in the plural. You have an array (actually a NodeList) of elements, but you're treating it like a single element. try adding `[0]` to get the first matching element. But why bother? `document.body` already contains the tag you're looking for. `document.body.classList.add("test")` would do the trick nicely.

Comment: Also note that your `test` function is not called on `load` event. You are calling the function by using the invocation operator: `()`. What happens is the returned value of `test`  function is set as the handler (your function returns `undefined`). Solution: remove the `()` operator.

Comment: Thanks guys fok javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix 'Typerror is undefined' message for a function in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118923/how-to-fix-typerror-is-undefined-message-for-a-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that it's `getElementsByTagName`, not `getElementByTagName` -- it's plural. It returns a list of elements.

To add a class to the first element in that list:

```
if ( document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className.match(/(?:^|\s)test(?!\S)/) ){
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className += " test";
    alert("test");
}
```

Comment: 1+ (As a side note, you can also just select the `body` element with `document.body`).

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an **array** of elements of psecified tag. For example, if you have 100500 `div` elements on your page `getElementsByTagName` will return an array with length of 100500 and it will contain all your `div` elements. And of course, `array` has not property `className`

If you want to select only one specific element you can specify an `id` attribute for it and call `getElementById` which returns you single element

In case of using `getElementsByTagName` you can try to get array of your elements, select the first item from it (zero index) and then read its' `className` property